# How to call controller actions of object built by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have an order object being created like so -

```
@order = @orthosis_spec.orders.build
```

I need to send an email from the order controller. I have tried adding action calls to the order create action, but this does not even get called.

How can I tap into the object creation when created using `.build`?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A callback? Although I'd advise against going that route for emails.

Comment: I just meant an action call, no callbacks. Thanks.

Comment: You don't; build just builds it. Why do you need to send an email specifically from the order controller?

Comment: The order holds varying products polymorphically. I want to use the order controller for sending emails with attachments for any possible product it is related to. I would rather write the functionality once for this in the order controller - instead of every time I create a new product. Thanks and sorry for the delay!